# Loop Infinito no While em C

Tags: c

Estou tenta fazer uma lista linear com alocação encadeada em C e estou caindo em um loop infinito.

```
void busca(Lista L, int x, No* ant, No* pont){
No ptr;

*pont = NULL;
*ant = L->ptLista;
ptr = (*ant)->prox;

while (ptr != NULL){
    if (ptr->valor < x){
        *ant = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->prox;
    }else{
        if(ptr->valor == x){
            *pont = ptr;
            printf("Numero encontrado\n");
        }

        ptr == NULL;
        printf("Saindo\n");
    }   
}}
```

(No = typedef struct no* No)
(Lista = typedef struct lista* Lista)
Esta função faz uma busca procurando o inteiro X. Porém quando o inteiro X é encontrado na lista o ptr não é setado para NULL e o while entra em um ciclo infinito. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Tem certeza de que aqui:  ptr == NULL; não deveria ser uma atribuição e não uma comparação para igualdade?

Comment: Bem observado kk, vlw